How do I change the date/time format in syslog-ng from `mmm [d]d hh:mm:ss` to `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss`?
I noticed that the default datetime format for logs in /var/log/messages is mmm [d]d hh:mm:ss, for example:
Jan  4 03:46:50 1.2.3.4 ntpclient[6952]: Failed resolving address to hostname pool.ntp.org: Try again
Jan  4 03:46:50 1.2.3.4 ntpclient[6952]: Failed resolving server pool.ntp.org: Network is down
Jan  4 03:46:50 1.2.3.4 process_monitor[2007]: cyclic NTP Update failed (servers pool.ntp.org)

I found a post here that describes updating the rsyslog.conf file, and although I made that change, it is only for syslog/rsyslog, not syslog-ng, so it makes no difference.
I looked for the equivalent configuration setting in the syslog-ng.conf file, but I can't find where to set it. I can't see anything in any @included configuration files either.
grep -Ei 'time|format|date' /etc/syslog-ng/syslog-ng.conf

and
grep -Eir 'time|format|date' /etc/syslog-ng/*.conf

both return nothing.

for that you need to modify the template of the message for the file destination. See the file destination docs for examples, and the date-related macros for a list of available macros. Something like:
   destination d_file {
    file("/var/log/messages"
         template("${YEAR}-${MONTH}-${DAY} ${HOUR}:${MIN}:${SEC} ${HOST} [${LEVEL}] ${MESSAGE}\n")
         template-escape(no));
};


Thank you +1 for that
